# Getting projection from vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, pyqgis, vector-layer

I am trying to set the projection on a raster to match that of a vector point layer. Thus I need to find out what is the projection of a given layer, to use it in the `GDAL.Dataset.SetProjection()` so that I can create the GeoTIFF with the appropriate projection.

How do I do that in QGIS using Python?

Comment: Another way to put it is: How to get the EPSG for the Layer?

Comment: Do you want to reproject the raster to the vector's CRS using Python? Please try to clarify.

Comment: @fccoelho In the python console: iface.activeLayer().crs().postgisSrid() returns only the EPSG code as an integer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Short answer**

```
qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer().crs().authid()
# returns: PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'EPSG:26913')
```

**Explanation**

`qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()` returns a reference to the active [QgsMapLayer](http://doc.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html).

[`QgsMapLayer.crs()`](http://doc.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#a40b79e2d6043f8ec316a28cb17febd6c) returns the crs or [QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem](http://doc.qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html) for the layer.

[`QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.authid()`](http://doc.qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html#a4382981b1233c7f0ca1c7ce7bdb670d3) returns  the Authority identifier for the crs as a [QString](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qstring.html).

However, this is assuming there is an active layer, it is of a vector type, and it has a valid crs. You will want to test for validity of those items before committing to reprojecting a raster.

If you are reprojecting, using GDAL.Dataset.SetProjection() will not suffice, since it will only assign a projection and not reproject (warp) the raster to the same as your vector layer.

Comment: I ended up using: layer.srs() to get the layer and then srs.epsg to get the EPSG code for the layer. Then, to generate the geotiff: see here: https://github.com/fccoelho/spatialKDE/blob/master/kernel.py in the to_geotiff method.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the active layer's CRS with:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
lyrCRS = layer.crs().authid() # returns a reference to the active QgsMapLayer

print(lyrCRS)
```