# How to access CRS of shapefile in standalone script?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I'm trying to access the CRS of a layer and use this to create a grid. I followed the answer in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34220/how-to-get-the-projection-from-a-vectorlayer-in-qgis) which works great in QGIS but I would like it to work in a standalone script. Here is a snippet:

```
for fname in glob.glob("C:\Users\moi\Desktop\Test\Grid\\" + "*.shp"):

    extent = QgsVectorLayer( fname, '', 'ogr' ).extent()
    centerx = (extent.xMinimum() + extent.xMaximum()) / 2
    centery = (extent.yMinimum() + extent.yMaximum()) / 2
    width = extent.xMaximum() - extent.xMinimum()
    height = extent.yMaximum() - extent.yMinimum()
    CRS = QgsMapLayer.crs(fname).authid()

    general.runalg("qgis:creategrid", 1000, 1000, width, height, centerx, centery, 1, CRS, None)
```

Running the above gives me the following error message:

> TypeError: QgsMapLayer.crs(): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QgsMapLayer'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bleh, answer was simple.

Just had to replace what I originally wrote:

```
CRS = QgsMapLayer.crs(fname).authid()
```

With this:

```
CRS = QgsVectorLayer( fname, '', 'ogr' ).crs().authid()
```

Works a treat, hope this helps someone!

Comment: I'm also interested in seeing if there are better or any other methods of obtaining a shapefile's CRS =)