# Get the CRS of a raster file in a standalone script - Qgis Python

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, pyqgis

In a standalone Qgis python script I would like to get the CRS of a raster file. The idea is that I ultimately want to reproject it (probably using `processing.runalg("gdalwarp ...` ) but I don't want to hardcode the origin CRS in the code.

I have seen directions like [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181731/set-crs-for-raster-in-qgsrasterlayer-pyqgis) but it all relies on the `iface`, which is apparently not straight-forward to use in a standaline script. Or [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149901/how-to-access-crs-of-shapefile-in-standalone-script), but it applies to shp and I didn't manage to adapt it to a raster layer

Is there an easier solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following to get the CRS of a raster:

```
crs = QgsRasterLayer("path/to/raster", "any_name").crs().authid()
```

Comment: @StéphaneHenriod - Most welcome ;)