# Automating massive raster import using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I need to import all the raster files in a folder in the QGIS 3.4 canvas. Each file is in a .asc format. How to do it using PyQGIS?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to get the current raster crs and then set the project default crs so the dialog does not show, see:

[how to get the projection from a vectorlayer in qgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34220/how-to-get-the-projection-from-a-vectorlayer-in-qgis)

[QGIS changing canvas CRS defaults to imported layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273252/qgis-changing-canvas-crs-defaults-to-imported-layer)

Another option is if all the raster crs are the same you could set the QGIS default crs manually in the Settings>Options>CRS tab.

Comment: Thanx. I just found out that the problem is relative only to QGIS 3., because in QGIS 2. it automatically assign the SRS to EPSG:4326 to rasters without any reference. This is not ideal, because I need EPSG:3003 but can be bearable, because the most important things is to avoid the popup asking me to set SRS for each file. Anyway Settings>Options>CRS doesn't solve the problem.